# How can I extract the raw JSON string from an OkHttp Response object?

Tags: android, json, okhttp

```
private static final String URL = "http://www.livroandroid.com.br/livro/carros/carros_{tipo}.json";

public static List<Carro> getCarros(Context context, String tipo) throws IOException {
    String url = URL.replace("{tipo}", tipo);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL)
            .build();
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    String json = response.body().toString();
    List<Carro> carros = parserJSON(context, json);
    return carros;
}
```

If I print out the value of the `json` variable when calling the `getCarros` method, I see the following message in my logcat:

> com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RealResponseBody@1e11866

How can I log the actual JSON string I received instead?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

(Originally answered for OkHttp version 2.5.0).

Replace

```
String json = response.body().toString();
```

with

```
String json = response.body().string();
```

`response.body` returns a `ResponseBody` object, which has its own `string` method: see the source [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.5.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody.java#L82).

Comment: Also applies to OkHttp 3.0.1

Comment: It helped me to reuse retrofit service(interface)

Comment: any solution for okhttp 3.12+ ?
body.string() does not exist.

Comment: Can you guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907506/how-to-get-the-flux-response-into-map?

Answer (score 1):

kotlin user try this code 100% tested

```
val result: String = Gson().toJson(response.body()!!.string())
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) What is kotlin user? Are you a kotlin user? How us that relevant?